# Android Dev Phone 3?

Tags: android

I'm wondering if there is any news about a "Android Dev Phone 3"? Is an updated hardware of the "Android Dev Phone 2" that is coming soon? (probably an unlocked version of the Nexus One)

Comment: I imagine it'd be listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Dev_Phone if any concrete information existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nexus One IS the unlocked version of the Nexus One!  It's sim unlocked and the bootloader is unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

There is no news or suggestion by Google, nor are there any leaks as of today.

Answer (score 0):

"The Nexus One is no longer available for direct purchase from Google, but will be made available through a partner for sale to registered developers. Please check back for more updates regarding developer availability."
http://www.google.com/support/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166508